# Oracle SQL count same field across multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, primavera

I have an oracle database that has the same name field in multiple tables. It kind of looks like this:

```
table1     table2     table3     table4
field      field      field      field
```

The common field in each table can either be 'yes', 'no', or null. I'm trying to get the value counts of all the fields in one query, but I can't figure it out. Basically I want this:

```
field     table1_cnt     table2_cnt     table3_cnt     table4_cnt
yes       20             25             30             35
no        35             25             15             5
null      8              6              7              5
```

I have this so far, but it only really works for one table, not multiple.

```
select field, count(*) as table1_cnt
from table1
group by field
_____________________________________
field     table1_cnt
yes       20
no        35
null      8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using join

```
select t1.field,table1_cnt,table2_cnt,table3_cnt,table4_cnt
from
(
select field, count(*) as table1_cnt
from table1
group by field
)t1 left join 
(
select field, count(*) as table2_cnt
from table2
group by field
)t2 on t1.field=t2.field left join
(
select field, count(*) as table3_cnt
from table3
group by field
)t3 on t1.field=t3.field left join
(
select field, count(*) as table4_cnt
from table4
group by field
)t2 on t1.field=t4.field
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that it helped u :)

Comment: @Nick . . . This does not work if the first table does not have all the values in the subsequent tables.  In addition, I don't think it counts `NULL` values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would recommend using `union all` and aggregate:

```
select field,
       sum(table_1), sum(table_2), sum(table_3), sum(table_4)
from ((select field, 1 as table_1, 0 as table_2, 0 as table_3, 0 as table_4 from table1) union all
      (select field, 0, 1, 0, 0 from table2) union all
      (select field, 0, 0, 1, 0 from table3) union all
      (select field, 0, 0, 0, 1 from table4) 
     ) t
group by field;
```

This has three advantages over using `left join`s:

1. *All* field values are included in the result, not just the values in the first table.
2. `NULL` values are included in the result.
3. `0` values are included, where appropriate (rather than `NULL` counts).

Comment: For my particular case I don't care about NULL or 0 values. These are values entered into the database by a form radio button and they are guaranteed to be 'Yes' or 'No'. There just happens to be multiple forms, with the same inputs, each with their own database table.